# rails_admin: control on admin users signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I installed rails_admin first with model name as rails_admin_user.
The first time I logged in, I clicked 'sign up' and created admin user account.
Now every time I want to login; there is a 'sign up' link still there.

Seems that anyone can create account for admin interface of rails_admin.

If this is true, please let me know how to restrict admin user creation process.

Comment: One way is to disable the register/sign_up route of devise. How to do that?

Comment: Answer for the comment above - http://stackoverflow.com/q/6734323/403596

Answer (score 9):

Hey, here is how you do it. Go to your user or member model, depending on how you set up devise, and remove registerable from devise attributes. This way the sign up link will disappear.

Comment: Works great ! If you do not restart your server in dev env, sign up will lead to an error. After a restart of rails server, the link is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Late but still good to share I think. You could do this to show signup for first user only, which will hopefully be you.

> devise :registerable if User.empty?