# How do I remove the Devise route to sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise

I'm using Devise in a Rails 3 app, but in this case, a user must be created by an existing user, who determines what permissions he/she will have.

Because of this, I want:

- To **remove the route for users to sign up**.
- To **still allow users to edit their profiles** (change email address and password) **after** they have signed up

How can I do this?

Currently, I'm effectively removing this route by placing the following before `devise_for :users`:

```
match 'users/sign_up' => redirect('/404.html')
```

That works, but I imagine there's a better way, right?

### Update

As Benoit Garret said, the best solution in my case is to skip creating the registrations routes en masse and just create the ones I actually want.

To do that, I first ran `rake routes`, then used the output to re-create the ones I wanted. The end result was this:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations] 
as :user do
  get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
  put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
end
```

Note that:

- I still have `:registerable` in my `User` model
- `devise/registrations` handles updating email and password
- Updating other user attributes - permissions, etc - is handled by a different controller

### Actual answer:

Remove the route for the default Devise paths; i.e.:

```
devise_for :users, path_names: {
  sign_up: ''
}
```

Comment: I actually think your original solution was much more simple, and clear. Is there any real problem with it security wise?

Comment: For some reason your updated solution kept throwing an error saying I needed the ID.  After an hour of hair pulling and many many server restarts, it somehow fixed itself.  I have no idea... but if someone else experiences that, keep trying!

Comment: @counterbeing - no problem that I know of, I just didn't like having unused routes or relying on ordering.

Comment: "Actual Answer" doesn't complete kill the route if it is redirected to from within devise controller.  Default behavior will still route you to sign-up path if you hit GET route like `https://example.com/users/`. See my answer below.

Comment: Security Flaw! The "Actual answer" that is shown only get's rid of the sign-up form, it does NOT get rid of the POST route that actually creates the user.

Comment: `path_names` solution is useful for disabling sign in. For sign out, I removed registerable module from User model.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I tried to do this as well, but [a thread on the devise google group](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/2e57d3bb14c1498f/c31a2647b102ff89) dissuaded me from searching for a really clean solution.

I'll quote José Valim (the Devise maintainer) :

> There isn't a straight-forward option. You can either provide a patch
>   or use :skip => :registerable and add only the routes you want.

The original question was :

> Is there any good way to remove a specific route (the delete route)
>   from Rails?

Comment: Quite correct. In fact, I proposed a patch and he politely declined: "Today, you can skip the whole controller. It is not optimal in terms of usage, but setting up the routes for the whole controller manually is pretty straightfoward.

I believe that excluding routes by name is just going to make the routes generation code more complicated (than it already is) because we won't be able to use Rails helpers (like resource, resources and friends)". https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1246#issuecomment-1736879

Comment: I don't know if this was the case when this answer was originally written, but the code in the quote from José is wrong. In Devise 3.4.1 it's `:skip => :registrations` not `:skip => :registerable`.

Answer (score 92):

you can do this in your model

```
# typical devise setup in User.rb
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

change it to:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

notice that the symbol `:registerable` was removed

That's it, nothing else is required. All routes and links to registration page are magically removed too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also removes the route to `edit_user_registration`, which I need. As I said, "they should still be able to edit their profiles."

Comment: Ahh, OK, well I normally get round this by installing [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/) gem, which lets users go to `localhost:3000/admin` where they can edit their account, even with the resisterable object removed. If that's not a viable solution, then take a look at [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/) which lets you stipulate who can and cannot access a resource. I tend to add roles like 'admin' or 'moderator' and lock everyone else out of the sign_up pages.

Comment: Using an admin section (which is built to allow editing of arbitrary records) to provide a way for users to edit their own profiles is the worst idea I've heard in a long time. Please nobody do this

Comment: How to disable `sign_in` in production?

Answer (score 31):

I had similar issue tried to remove [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/) paths for *create* and *new* :

#### before:

```
 devise_for :users
```

*rake routes*

```
accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)           devise/invitations#edit
       user_invitation POST   /users/invitation(.:format)                  devise/invitations#create
   new_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/new(.:format)              devise/invitations#new
                       PUT    /users/invitation(.:format)                  devise/invitations#update
```

#### after

```
devise_for :users , :skip => 'invitation'
devise_scope :user do
  get "/users/invitation/accept", :to => "devise/invitations#edit",   :as => 'accept_user_invitation'
  put "/users/invitation",        :to => "devise/invitations#update", :as => nil
end
```

*rake routes*

```
accept_user_invitation GET    /users/invitation/accept(.:format)                 devise/invitations#edit
                       PUT    /users/invitation(.:format)                        devise/invitations#update
```

**note 1** devise scope https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes

**note 2** I'm applying it on devise_invitable but it will work with any devise *able feature

**Important note:** see that devise_scope is on *user* not *users* ? that's correct, watch out for this ! It can cause lot of pain giving you this problem:

```
Started GET "/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=xxxxxxx" for 127.0.0.1 
Processing by Devise::InvitationsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"invitation_token"=>"6Fy5CgFHtjWfjsCyr3hG"}
 [Devise] Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/invitation/accept?  invitation_token=6Fy5CgFHtjWfjsCyr3hG".
This may happen for two reasons:

1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

  devise_scope :user do
     match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
  end

 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
   If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for. For others who use this solution, I had to append /:id to the put route definition.

Answer (score 22):

I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370164/disabling-devise-registration-for-production-environment-only/5370688#5370688) similar to this one and wanted to share an answer @chrisnicola gave. In the post they were attempting to only block user signup's during production.

You could also modify the registrations controller. You can use something like this:

In **"app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb"**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    flash[:info] = 'Registrations are not open.'
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def create
    flash[:info] = 'Registrations are not open.'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

This will override devise's controller and use the above methods instead. They added flash messages incase that someone somehow made it to the sign_up page. You should also be able to change the redirect to any path you like.

Also in **"config/routes.rb"** you can add this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Leaving it like this will allow you to use the standard devise edit your profile. If you wish you can still override the edit profile option by including

```
  def update
  end
```

in the **"app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb"**

Answer (score 14):

This is an old question - but I recently had solve the same issue and came up with a solution which is far more elegant than:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations] 
as :user do
  get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
  put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
end
```

And it gives the default names for the named routes (like `cancel_user_registration`) without being excessively verbose.

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]

# Recreates the Devise registrations routes
# They act on a singular user (the signed in user)
# Add the actions you want in 'only:'
resource :users,
    only: [:edit, :update, :destroy],
    controller: 'devise/registrations',
    as: :user_registration do
  get 'cancel'
end
```

`rake routes` output with the default devise modules:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

Answer (score 13):

You can override the "devise_scope" by placing it before the "devise_for".

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/users/sign_up",  :to => "sites#index"
end

devise_for :users
```

Not sure if this is the best way but its my solution currently, as it just redirects back to the sign in page.

Comment: I took a similar approach, but wanted the URL to change also, so went with `    get "/users/sign_up",  :to => redirect("/")`

Comment: So simple and easiest solving. But this solving has one minute problem. The address is remained. If you enter `/users/sign_up` then you'll be access to the `sites#index` not `sign_up` but address still be remained `/users/sign_up`.

Answer (score 5):

I liked @max's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31779657/956688), but when trying to use it I ran into an error due to `devise_mapping` being nil.

I modified his solution slightly to one that seems to address the issue. It required wrapping the call to `resource` inside `devise_scope`.

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]

devise_scope :user do
  resource :users,
           only: [:edit, :update, :destroy],
           controller: 'devise/registrations',
           as: :user_registration do
    get 'cancel'
  end
end
```

Note that `devise_scope` expects the singular `:user` whereas `resource` expects the plural `:users`.

Answer (score 4):

Do This in routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}, :skip => [:registrations]
  as :user do
    get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
    put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
end

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/sign_in",  :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/sign_up",  :to => "devise/registrations#new"
  end
```

you will get an error now while you come to sign in page, to fix it. 
Do this change in: app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb

```
<% if  request.path != "/sign_in" %>
    <%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
        <%= link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(resource_name) %><br />
    <% end -%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This worked for me  (I only used the `devise_for` and the `as` block ) and I had to remove `:registerable` in the model.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this to work well without messing with routes or adding application controller methods.  My approach is to override the devise method.  Add this to `app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb`
I've omitted the other methods for brevity.

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  ...
  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  ....
end
```

Also to remove illusion that this path is still reachable from other views you might also want to remove this code from `app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb`

```
<%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 2):

For others in my case.
With `devise (3.5.2)`.
I successfully removed the routes to signup, but kept the ones to edit the profile, with the following code.

```rb
#routes.rb
devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]
as :user do
  get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
  put '/users(.:format)' => 'devise/registrations#update', as: 'user_registration'
  patch '/users(.:format)' => 'devise/registrations#update'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the slightly different route I went. It makes it so you don't have to override the `devise/shared/_links.html.erb` view.

In `app/models/user.rb`:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', as: 'user_registration'
  get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', as: 'edit_user_registration'
  delete 'users' => 'devise/registrations#destroy', as: 'registration'
end
```

#### Before:

```
$ rake routes | grep devise
           new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
               user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
       destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy
              user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
          new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
         edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
                            PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                            PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
   cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                     devise/registrations#cancel
          user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#create
      new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                    devise/registrations#new
     edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       devise/registrations#edit
                            PATCH  /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                            PUT    /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                            DELETE /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#destroy
```

#### After:

```
$ rake routes | grep devise
           new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
               user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
       destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy
              user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
          new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
         edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
                            PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                            PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
          user_registration PUT    /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
     edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       devise/registrations#edit
               registration DELETE /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: If you do not want to have redundant routes, skip all default routes, i.e. `devise_for :users, skip: :all`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for a hard solution. I used the below approaches.

1. Delete the sign_up form from page (path  devise/registrations/new.html.erb) and replace it with custom info.
2. Redirect the incoming traffic to some other page. Like below in `routes.rb`

```
    get "/users/sign_up", to: redirect('/')

    post "/users/sign_up", to: redirect('/')
```

Make sure to write it before `devise_for :users`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found it a bit bad practise to redirect users from the registration page. So my solution is basically is not using `:registrable` at all.

What I did was to create a similar page like edit user details which looked like:

```
<%= form_tag(update_user_update_path, method: :post) do %>  
    <br>
    <%= label_tag(:currPassword, 'Current password:') %> <%= password_field_tag(:currPassword) %> <br>
    <%= label_tag(:newPassword, 'New password:') %> <%= password_field_tag(:newPassword) %> <br>
    <%= label_tag(:newPasswordConfirm, 'Confirm new password:') %> <%= password_field_tag(:newPasswordConfirm) %> <br>
    <%= submit_tag('Update') %>
<% end %>
```

So this form submits into a new post end point that updates the password, which looks like:

```
  def update
    currPass = params['currPassword']
    newPass1 = params['newPassword']
    newPass2 = params['newPasswordConfirm']
    currentUserParams = Hash.new()
    currentUserParams[:current_password] = currPass
    currentUserParams[:password] = newPass1
    currentUserParams[:password_confirmation] = newPass2
    @result = current_user.update_with_password(currentUserParams)
  end
```

Later on you can use the `@result` in your view to tell the user whether the password is updated or not.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the routes there are a whole bunch of other problems that come with that. The easiest method I have found is to do the following.

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :dont_allow_user_self_registration

  private

  def dont_allow_user_self_registration
    if ['devise/registrations','devise_invitable/registrations'].include?(params[:controller]) && ['new','create'].include?(params[:action])
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Works, but do you really wanna run this method on every single action?

Answer (score -7):

You could modify the `devise` gem itself. First, run this command to find the installed location of using:

`gem which devise`

Let's suppose the path is: 
`/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.2/lib/devise`

Then go to

`/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.2/lib/devise/lib/devise/rails` and edit `routes.rb` in that directory. There is a method called `def devise_registration(mapping, controllers)` which you can modify to get rid of the new action. You can also completely remove the mappings for `devise_registration`

Comment: +1 for an alternate suggestion, but forking a gem seems less desirable to me than putting some awkward code in my routes.

Comment: in general practice this is big No-No ! you should keep gems as they are and if you need to change something just monkey patch them

Comment: I agree with you in this case, but in general I don't think you should shy away from making changes to libraries/gems you use as an alternative to monkey patching code in a bunch of different places. 
The ability to mould a library to your needs is is one of the big pluses of using open-source code IMO.

Comment: If you're going to modify the gem, at least fork it and point your Gemfile to your monkey patched gem (on github for example).   I've done this on several occasions.  Process is:  fork gem, clone your fork locally, monkey patch your local version, push to your remote repo and point Gemfile to it.
(i.e. `gem 'devise', github: 'yourusername/devise', branch: "master"`)